# Assign multiple values to Pandas series but become NaN

Tags: python, pandas, series

If I apply some calculations or assign a scalar to some values in a Pandas series, it works as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([1.1, 2.2, 3.4, 5.6], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
print(x)
x[['a', 'b']] = x[['a', 'b']]/2
print(x)
```

Result:

```
a    1.1
b    2.2
c    3.4
d    5.6
dtype: float64
a    0.55
b    1.10
c    3.40
d    5.60
dtype: float64
```

However, if I assign some values from the same series to other values, they become NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([1.1, 2.2, 3.4, 5.6], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
print(x)
x[['a', 'b']] = x[['c', 'd']]
print(x)
```

Result:

```
a    1.1
b    2.2
c    3.4
d    5.6
dtype: float64
a    NaN
b    NaN
c    3.4
d    5.6
dtype: float64
```

Why?

Comment: index alignment, you should do `x[['a','b']] = x[['c','d']].to_numpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `x[['c', 'd']]` is still a Series with index:

```
>>> x[['c', 'd']]
c    3.4
d    5.6
```

so Pandas could only assign these values to slots `'c'` and `'d'` on the left-hand side. And: The left-hand side is expecting the right-hand side to provide values to slots `'a'` and `'b'`, but these can't be found on the right-hand side.

What you could do, is

```
x[['a', 'b']] = x[['c', 'd']].to_numpy()
```